# Not receiving notifications for new messages

Tags: support, notifications, globalinbox

For the past few days (I *think* since the move to the New York data center) I have not been receiving notifications of new messages. If someone @'s me or comments on one of my posts, I get a badge on my user's page responses tab but no icon on the stack exchange drop down menu on the main site.

I have the same problem on all SE sites I am active in.

UPDATE: Did someone change something? I got my first notification today (21 Feb 2013) at 15:12 UTC.

Comment: I blame the gnomes ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek durned gnomes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances we've seen this in were browser crashes or a tab left open with the inbox expanded - this reads notifications as soon as they are received.  Nothing has changed on our side since the move when real-time functionality was re-enabled (about an hour after the move).

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd wait a few days to make sure everything was working again and, of course, completely forgot because everything was working again. Don't know if it was a cache issue since I think I had the same issue on two iOS devices and my linux laptop but it's fixed now, so marking as accepted.